# java reader ends String with null

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm using a common way to read text file in java:

```
public String readIndex() throws IOException{
        if(!fileExisits)
            return "";
        String indexInFile = "";
        while((indexInFile = reader.readLine())!=null){
            indexInFile += reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("indexxxxxxxx: " + indexInFile);
        }
        System.out.println("reader get: " + indexInFile);
        return indexInFile;
    }
```

and the output is :
is file :: true

```
indexxxxxxxx: 1fefefe\fefeef
indexxxxxxxx: effe
indexxxxxxxx: effe
indexxxxxxxx: null
reader get: null
null
```

as you can see in the last line the output String `indexInFile` is being set to `null`.
my reader is:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

any suggestions why it happens? hopes that I write all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

When the last line is encountered the following `reader.readLine()` will return zero. Then the condition of the while loop, the assignment `indexInFile=null` will be called. The while loop will exit because `(indexInFile=null)==null)`.

Also, you can possibly have a `null` inside the for loop since you call `reader.readLine()` there. The following code will fix your problem, I think:

```
public String readIndex() throws IOException{
    if(!fileExisits)
        return "";
    String line;
    String indexInFile = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
        indexInFile += line;
        System.out.println("indexxxxxxxx: " + line);
    }
    System.out.println("reader get: " + indexInFile);
    return indexInFile;
}
```

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas why would you want to solve this? It seems to me that it is the intended behaviour, unless you would like to have the last line in the file?

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas I saw another problem in your code. I updated my anwser accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the second `readLine()`:

```
public String readIndex() throws IOException{
    if(!fileExisits)
        return "";
    String indexInFile = "";
    while((indexInFile = reader.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println("indexxxxxxxx: " + indexInFile);
    }
    System.out.println("reader get: " + indexInFile);
    return indexInFile;
}
```

Your already reading the line in your `while` condition. So when you reach the last line of text you are going to right away read the `nextLine` again before it can break out of the `loop` which will return `null` because there are no more lines.  That is why `null` is being printed.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling readLine twice per loop step. Also readLine strips the trailing newline char(s).

```
    StringBuilder totalText = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        totalText.append(line).append("\r\n");
        System.out.println("Line: " + line);
    }
    System.out.println("All: " + totalText.toString());
```

Using StringBuilder will greatly improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `reader.ready()` to check (So you will also get rid of the doubled readLine())

```
public String readIndex() throws IOException{
    if(!fileExisits)
        return "";
    String indexInFile = "";
    while(reader.ready()){
        indexInFile += reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("indexxxxxxxx: " + indexInFile);
    }
    System.out.println("reader get: " + indexInFile);
    return indexInFile;
}
```